# how to do 2 while loop mysqli_query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

My code below does not work properly:

```
<?php
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bicycle_list");
while($res1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $bike_id = $res1['bike_id']; 
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bicycle WHERE bicyle_id = $bike_id");
    while($res2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
?> 
        <td><?php echo $res2['name']; ?></td>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

how do i correct this?

Comment: "does not work properly" **HOW**? General rule: if you're running nested queries, and the inner query depends on values from the outer query, then almost ALWAYS you can/should re-write to use a SINGLE `JOIN`ed query instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To format a code block, you can highlight it and click `{}` in the edit toolbar or `ctl-k`.  Enclosing in backquotes is for inline code and doesn't work well for code blocks.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind. i'm new in PHP and not good at sql. btw, if ever, can u give me a sample query for this? thanks!

Comment: What is this doing that is not working properly? We can't give a sample query if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @JustinE already solved by Marc and Andy. correct sample query below given by Andy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a SQL JOIN.  Your basic query will look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM bicycle_list INNER JOIN bicycle ON bicycle.bicycle_id = bicycle_list.bikeid;
```

But you should really read a tutorial about how SQL JOINs work rather than just using this code as-is.

Comment: Beware `SELECT *` in a join context. There's a good possibility you may lose access to some columns in an associative fetch if they're similarly named.  In general, never `SELECT *` in production code. Best to be explicit about the columns you need.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Agreed.  I usually phrase it more directly: "SELECT * is a bug," but only wanted to introduce one concept here.